# Python re escaping raises TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Tags: python, escaping, multiline, python-re

I have an error log of a few thousands line and I would like to match all the occurences of these type:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py", line 83, in upload_detection_image
    put_response = s3_object.put(Body=image, ContentType="image/jpeg")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token has expired.
```

More in general, I would like to match some text starting with a given string, and ending with another string. The text could be multiline. The problem is that the beginning and end of the text could contain some dedicated regex characters that might require to be escaped.
My attempt:

```
pattern = rf"Traceback(.*){re.escape('botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token has expired.')}",
re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

It gives me error on `findall`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 300, in _compile
    raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Unrelated: I suspect you want `re.DOTALL`, not `re.MULTILINE`.

Comment: And use `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Typo: You have a comma at the end of the line that assigns `pattern`. That makes it a tuple insetad of a string.

Comment: All of this contributes to the final answer. Is there a way to avoid nested groups? Otherwise I would have a match that basically match all the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your comments contribute to the final solution:

```
pattern = rf"Traceback(.*?){re.escape('botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token has expired.')}"
results = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `re.MULTILINE`? You have no `^` or `$` in the regexp.

Comment: Right, no need for it. I'll fix the answer above. Do you know how can I avoid having the regex matching almost the entire text? I think there are nested matched

Comment: You should use a negative lookaround so it doesn't have `Traceback` inside the match.